# POST service parameter won't bind to request body with array as a property Angular2 typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, http, typescript, angular

I'm trying to send a complex object that will have two int and one byte array properties to a webapi post service. If I send the parameters with only the two int properties populated the body value binds to the service parameters.  Once I populate the array the service parameters are null.

The overall purpose of the app is to send a file in segments to a database to be saved.

Has anyone dealt with anything similar before? Thank you for any help.

Here is the service function making the http POST call

```
uploadChunk(params: FileParams, success) {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ fileId: new Number(params.fileId), chunkId: new Number(params.chunkId), chunk: new Array(params.chunk) });
    //let body = JSON.stringify({ fileId: params.fileId, chunkId: params.chunkId, chunk: new Array(params.chunk), totalSegments: 0, valid: new Boolean(false), fileName: " ", dateCreated: " ", un: " ", accessToken: " " });
    //let body = JSON.stringify({ params });
    let url = this._fileUrl + 'api/file/UploadChunk';
    debugger;

    return this.http.post(url, body, this.postOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then((res: Response) => success(res.json()))
        .catch(this.error);
}
```

Here is the FileParams object

```
export class FileParams {    
    fileId: number;
    chunkId: number;
    chunk: Int8Array;
}
```

The header im using in my service

```
postHeaders      = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' });
```

Incase it's relevant here's the start of the service method

```
[HttpPost]
public int UploadChunk([FromBody]FileUploadParams c)
{ }
```

Comment: `chunk: new Array(params.chunk)`. If `params.chunk` is an integer. This will create an `params.chunk.length` of `null` objects inside the array. Is this intentional?

Comment: params.chunk is an Int8Array, putting it in new Array() was the only way I could get valid json for the array.  Here's an example of what the json string could look like `{"fileId":"51","chunkId":"1","chunk":[{"0":-1,"1":-40,"2":-1,"3":-32,"4":0,"5":16}]}`